# Docker Desktop Log Location (not Containers)

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

I am getting the following error when I start Docker Desktop:

[image: Docker failed to initialize Docker Desktop is shutting down]

I am trying to get some more info on what went wrong, but all googling for log locations is leading me to `C:\ProgramData\Docker\containers`.  That location is for specific containers, not for Docker Desktop in general.

**Where does Docker Desktop keep logs about its startup issues?**

Answer (score 9):

Turns out the logs are here:

> C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Docker\log\host

and here:

> C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Docker

This issue had to do with the proxy settings in settings.json found here:

> C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Docker

I deleted all the lines (4 or 5 of them) that had the word "Proxy" in it and then docker started up.  Details found here: https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-failed-to-initialize/111341/17

Comment: What about Linux(Ubuntu)?

Comment: Also, would love to add the Mac log location too?